# Ubuntu MaaS Raid Preseed

Tags: server, system-installation, raid, maas

Straight to the problem. I need a raid configured during the maas node commissioning via preseed file and I'm unable to find any meaningful documentation on how to do it. For example I need a preseed raid configuration for 3 disks, 2 disks or more than 3 disks.

Or if there is another method that would create a raid during the installation other than preseed changes.

Any suggestion/script is welcome.